# Popcorn-Time movies error loading data, try again later

Tags: macos, torrent

The error appears when choosing the movies tab. I am noticing it in Popcorn-Time Version 0.3.5-4 (0.3.5-4), OS X 10.10.1.

Also noticed that the movie thumbnails are not appearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by clearing the parent directory `/Users/SOME_USER/Library/Application Support/Popcorn-Time`. (Replace `SOME_USER`)

I also have to clear all cache and data.

I also got the latest version from the continuous build in http://ci.popcorntime.io/job/Popcorn-Time/

**Update**: I also use this technique to debug. I run the app in the command line.

```
$ pwd
/Applications/Popcorn-Time.app/Contents/MacOS
$ ./node-webkit
```

Noticed this error (replace xxx with the username).

```
[61835:0207/235212:ERROR:leveldb_database.cc(280)] Failed to open LevelDB database
    from /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Popcorn-Time/IndexedDB/app_host_0.indexeddb.leveldb,
    IO error: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Popcorn-Time/IndexedDB/app_host_0.indexeddb.leveldb/LOCK:
    No further details. (ChromeMethodPFE: 15::LockFile::1)
```

I deleted `/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Popcorn-Time/IndexedDB` and the issue disappears.